# Metric spaces exersice

Tags: real-analysis

proof that the set $A= \{(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{m}) \in R^2: n,m \in N\}$ is not closed with the usual metric.

so I try to get the point (0,0) and I try to use the Archimedean property to show that there are numbers greater than (0,0) between 0 and 1 on both the y-axis and x-axis and so I can construct a ball that is both in A and outside of A but I don't know if I'm right.

Comment: THat's pretty much it! Also, notice that every point of the form $(0,1/m)$ and $(1/n,0)$ is a limit point of $A$, but none of them are in $A$.

Comment: but i can not use limit

Comment: Accumulation points, if you’d prefer that term.

Comment: What are you actually asking about? You've found a point which is a limit point and shown that it isn't in the set, and you've clearly demonstrated that you can prove that this is a limit point but doesn't belong to A, and you seem to understand your own proof. Yet at the end "I don't know if I'm right". How is this even a question?

Comment: so I do not know if I am correct using the Archimedean property, because I found the points but I do not know to conclude with those points.

Comment: $(0,0)\in \overline A$ iff every nbhd $U$ of $(0,0)$ contains a member of $A$....If $U$ is a nbhd of $(0,0)$ then there  is an open ball $B$ of radius $r>0$ and centered at $(0,0), $ with $U\supset B.$ There exists $n\in\Bbb N$ with $1/n<r/2.$  So $(1/n,1/n)\in B\cap A\subseteq U\cap  A.$